# Mysql Fulltext relevance calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, full-text-search

I have a table in MySQL which stores tags as comma separated string.

Those strings can contain spaces.

I need to make make a query where `relevance` will be based on how many exact same tags are present. Is it possible with `MATCH AGAINST` ?

problem is: tag `some tag bla bla` (few words) seems to provide much higher relevance than `someothertag`, which I suppose is because it contains multiple words

SQL query looks something like:

```
SELECT `table`.*, 
MATCH (table.tags) AGAINST ('"tag1" "tag2" "tag3 bla bla"') as relevance 
FROM `table` 
WHERE MATCH (table.tags) AGAINST ('"tag1" "tag2" "tag3 bla bla"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Comment: InnoDB will weight words relative the how rare it is in the whole index, and regardless of being a complete tag or not. You could get the count with a MyISAM-fulltext search, but generally, a fulltext search is not the right tool for this. You *may* get it to work your way, but it will be patch-work. An implementation of tags would be to store one tag(id) per row in a seperate table. Even with MyISAM, you can get results you may not like: with a tagcolumn `a, b, a c d` (assuming these are words) you will find non-existing tags like "a b", "a c", "c d", "c-d", "b a", "a b a", "c", "d", ...

Comment: @Solarflare is there any simple fix to current set up? will any symbol other than letter be perceived as delimiter too?

Comment: You mean a fix to keep using your (unrecommended) fulltext approach? As I said, it will be patch-work. Words consist of "letters, digits, and underscores" (plus one `'`), everything else is a delimiter. So you could, if you don't use it otherwise, use the understore and store combined tags as e.g. "tag3_bla_bla", then one tag = one word (you would not need the `""` in your search anymore). To get your word count, you would need to use MyISAM (so e.g. no transactions) or write a function that counts words in the rows found by the fulltext search (`select *, myfunc(tags, 'tag3_bla_bla') ...`).

Comment: Tagging should be done with a table of tags, not `FULLTEXT`.